# How do I use a question mark '?' in a Zend_Db_Select where() clause?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have the following MySQL query that I'm trying to translate into an equivalent Zend select() statement:

```
SELECT `entity_id` FROM `my_table` WHERE `attribute_id` IN (541,554,555,556) \
AND LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(`value`), '-', '')) REGEXP '([^[:space:]]* )?$param$'
```

`$param` is a PHP variable that's been filtered to include only alphanumeric characters.

Here is what I have so far with a Zend select() statement:

```
$db->select()
   ->from('my_table', 'entity_id')
   ->where('attribute_id IN (?)', array(541,554,555,556))
   ->where('LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM('
       . $db->quoteIdentifier('value')
       . '), "-", "")) REGEXP "([^[:space:]]* )?'
       . $param
       . '$"');
```

The SQL that's actually being output, when `$param = 'foo'`:

```
SELECT `entity_id` FROM `my_table` WHERE (attribute_id IN (541, 554, 555, 556)) \
AND (LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(`value`), "-", "")) REGEXP "([^[:space:]]* )foo$")
```

I need to be able to tell where() to not try and replace the question mark. How?

Comment: I realize I can use the equivalent `REGEXP "([^[:space:]]* ){0,1}foo$`. I still want to know if it's possible to use '?' in a `select()` statement without it being replaced.

Comment: The issue is how to escape the `?` character so that it will not be treated as a placeholder, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I believe you can simply replace the "?" string with a Zend_Db_Expr('?').

In your case, I think you'd want to replace the whole second WHERE clause with:

```
->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('LOWER(REPLACE...'))
```

Something along those lines...

Comment: I wrapped the entire `LOWER(REPLACE...` in the `Zend_Db_Expr` as you suggested but it's still exhibiting the same behavior.

Comment: @nachito: Are you sure this isn't working? I tried it locally on my side and got exactly the SQL you want.

Comment: @DavidWeinraub I tried it again and it worked. My mistake. Thanks to you both

Comment: Question isn't for Magento, but in case someone ends up here (as I did) looking for a solution to this problem (and is using Magento), this worked for me: `$collection->getSelectSql()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr($yourRegexpCondition), null, Varien_Db_Select::TYPE_CONDITION);`. I hope it helps!